# How to find the state of the art algorithm for a specific problem

Tags: publications, mathematics, computer-science, literature-search

Are there any good methods for doing this? I can find papers with algorithms, but they usually do not show their computational results with the same problem sets and the publishing year of two papers is usually different so they will most likely use different equipment for solving the problems.

Edit:
By problem, I am referring also to the specific size of the problem, memory usage and other characteristics of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried speaking to an or a more senior researcher at your institution advisor?

Comment: The state of the art may not be the best choice for your particular problem. Engineering judgement is required.

Comment: You search Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JonCuster - yeah, I heard of this [state-of-the-art algorithm for multiplying very large numbers in only _O(n log n)_](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I generally go through review papers in the field and try to cite them as well if they have any sentence in the paper **"claiming that the previous method is SOTA"**.
2. There are also benchmark sites.
3. Famous datasets even have their personal benchmarks linked to their sites.
4. You could use research gate or any other forum and ask a question there.
5. You could try a keyword search on google scholar and see if any paper claims to do so.

Regarding the difference in setting, generally the "well-acclaimed" SOTA papers don't have these issues. At least that's what I've noticed majorly in my field.

If that is the case, then I suggest making a small study within the paper covering all the results in the different settings. (Please do correct me if I'm wrong here).

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misunderstanding about algorithm efficiency and its study. A good course in algorithms and data structures should correct that.

I'll assume here that you actually *mean* [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) and not just a useful computer program. They are not the same thing. Some useful programs, while they may contain algorithms, have their performance dominated by other non-algorithmic concerns. The performance there might, indeed, be tied to a particular kind of dataset for which small deviations result in wildly different performance.

Algorithms are judged good or bad based on theoretical concerns, not by running them on sample data. The theoretical measures make them independent of hardware within certain bounds. A fast algorithm will run faster than a slow algorithm on different computers that have a similar architecture (see caveats below). Some algorithms (bubble sort) are always bad. Others are always better (selection sort). Still others are "always" good (merge sort, but see caveats).

So, the "different equipment" idea is a red herring, provided that the equipment has a similar architecture.

Caveats, and there are quite a few.

Some algorithms require a lot of memory (quick sort on a large set) because they are highly recursive. If a machine has insufficient *fast* memory then quick sort on a large data set will be limited by the, independent, efficiency of the memory system.

Some "slowish" algorithms work well on small data sets and can be preferred over "fastish" algorithms if the data set is expected to be small. But these things are known and are normally incorporated into working software. For example, in quick sort once a "split" results in a segment of size 10 or so, a quadratic algorithm will take over to complete the sort. But that is just good software design, and it uses known, theoretical, results for the various options.

However, if the architecture of a machine changes drastically (as a GPU differs from a CPU), then the game changes and some algorithms that are fast on one will be slower on the other. For example, still sorting things, if an architecture makes comparisons "free" then an algorithm that uses lots of comparisons, rather than rearrangements, will be preferred *on that architecture*. But, again, this is based on the theoretical considerations that measures the various kinds of operations required by an algorithm.

So, to answer your question, you need to look at the theoretical measures, and these are normally provided by authors.

Another caveat. There are some applied problems that are fairly ill structured and haven't (as yet) yielded to the theoretical analysis assumed above. Perhaps a bit of chaos is involved. For these, some empirical measures might be required at the moment. But some of those sorts of problems can also drive people to invent new architectures that can efficiently handle the problems. But, the same sort of problem also drives the theoreticians to invent new algorithms that *are* amenable to a general analysis of efficiency. But, the results will, most likely, be reported in theoretical terms, not timings on specific hardware. This is probably what you are seeing. And, hopefully, part of their analysis includes limits on when the algorithm can be expected to behave well.

Comment: I guess this answer applies to comparing a bunch of kinds of sort, but good luck on your "theoretical" evaluation of any machine or statistical learning approach.

Comment: @Libor, actually, any algorithm (provided it actually is an algorithm) can be analyzed and its efficiency predicted. Randomness, for example, is not an obstacle. Some things are harder than others of course. But algorithmics isn't a dead art.

Comment: Aight well you go theoretically tell me which autoencoder design has the best performance and I'll just be waiting over here.

Comment: @Libor, good, you do that.

Comment: @Libor  And, there are some things done that are of interest but don't fit the definition of algorithm. I don't include those, as being out of scope of the question.

Comment: I think this answer is either plain wrong, or you are using more the word "algorithm" differently from what many people are used to.

Comment: @user2316602, see the edit. Algorithm has a formal definition in CS and mathematics (and note the tags). I'm referring to that meaning, not some informal synonym for "computer program". The meaning of words matter, I think. If you want an answer to a broader question, then pose it.

Comment: Yes, that's the wikipedia link for algorithm. The point is that many algorithms are not neatly amenable to efficiency analysis as you've described, and that ***efficiency and performance are not synonyms no matter how many times you conflate them***.

Comment: @Libor, are you asking me to answer a different question than the one posed by the OP? If so, then state it. I think there is a lot of apples and oranges comparisons going on here, or algorithms and programs, at least.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I understand that there are different connotations of the word "efficient" depending on the problem I am facing. I did not want to say that there is only one efficient algorithm for a specific topic. My question was only about finding the best algorithm for a specific problem (which considers memory usage, the size of the problem, etc.) in a big pile of academic papers on the internet.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that the word "algorithm" is used differently in separate domains. In Machine Learning, while "architectures" are coined as algorithms in some instances, they aren't exactly bound by the same rules as to how buffy as mentioned them to be. The way buffy has put the statement is correct for how algorithms are meant to be but incorrect as to how algorithms are "perceived" in different fields". *Theoretical measures don't bound algorithms in other fields and I think that is the issue here. And there aren't also any "generizability" issues in general algorithm studies.

Comment: @Aymous, I realize that people outside CS and math might use terms informally. But I also depended on the question's specific tags. And in Math and CS, algorithm has a specific meaning that has been stable for over half a century. A statement about algorithms may not apply to a non-algorithm. I suspect, now that the OP actually meant something else than what is literally stated. In part,  I was trying to jumpstart the education of the OP who has some confusions somewhere. But they asked about why algorithm papers have a certain structure and I wrote about that. Not about other things.

Comment: @Aymous, and your answer, while I think it is more about "useful computer  programs" than algorithms (and fine in that context), may be more what the OP here was interested in. Perhaps they will enlighten us.

Comment: @Buffy I actually meant that within CS itself, the term algorithm is used differently! Many places in CS, they call "useful computer programs" as "algorithms". I think that's where the confusion arose. I completely agree with what you have said regarding algorithms but the word has a taken a different meaning in a few fields within CS itself.

Comment: @Buffy I did upvote your answer and consider it very useful. Do you recommend me to rename my question to "the state of the art program" instead?

Comment: I think that people who study "algorithms and data structures" have a formal definition of an algorithm that differs from what other people use, even within TCS. I think unless specifically stated, this should not be assumed to be the definition meant by OP and I, therefore think the quitestion is fine. Note that I am saying this as someone who does algorithms specifically, so I am used to the meaning Buffy uses.

Comment: Another reason for the gap between theoretical and practical efficiency is that theorists mostly care about worst-case complexity (and potentially some abstract notion of average-case complexity). Often, these cases are not quite representative for practical inputs. A prominent case are SAT solvers, where the best techniques have a worse theoretical complexity than others, but are faster at solving practical instances (millions of variables).